# Concatenate with parameter in command substitution

Tags: bash

If I want to set a value like:

```
key="some"
value=$(cat ${filename} | grep ${key}"string" | cut -d 'string' -f2)
```

What do I do to get the `${key}"string"` to work? It doesn't handle the `${key}` variable to concatenate it with string. I want to do:

```
cat $filename | grep "somestring" | cut...
```

Comment: `key=some; echo 'somestring' | grep -o "${key}s"` outputs `somes`

Comment: What you are doing should work.

Comment: yeah, thanks, something must be wrong with the cut piece

Comment: Use one call to `awk`: `awk -v k="$key" '$0 ~ k"string" {print $2}' "$filename"`

Comment: @chepner: It looks like the desired logic is: output what comes _after_ the match, so you can't use the default `FS`; `awk -F "${key}string" 'NF >= 2 { print $2 }'` may work (assuming just 1 match per line and escaping of regex metacharacters in the field-separator string, if needed).

Comment: Note that you should avoid the [Useless Use of `cat` — UUoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat/11710888#11710888).

Answer (score 3):

To **properly concatenate variable reference `${key}` with literal `"string"`, *embed* the variable reference inside the double-quoted string**:

```
key="some"
... | grep "${key}string" | ...
```

<sup>Note how enclosing the variable name in `{...}` is actually *required* now, to tell the shell where the variable name ends. [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) points out in a comment elsewhere:

"`${key}` is the *canonical* way to perform parameter expansion. The braces can optionally be dropped when they aren't necessary to enclose an expansion operator or to disambiguate the parameter name. "</sup>

With the *specific* sample value `"some"`, your concatenation (`${key}"string"`) would have worked the same, but not *generally*, because using `${key}` *unquoted* makes it subject to [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), notably *word splitting*, which will break the `grep` command if the value of variable `${key}` happens to contain *whitespace*.

---

The main problem with your code, however, is that **you're passing a *multi-character string* to `cut -d` in order to specify a delimiter, whereas only a *single character* is supported.**

If you have *GNU* `grep`, you can try the following:

```
key="some"
value=$(grep -Po "${key}string"'\K.*$' "${filename}")
```

This will return everything *after* `"${key}string"` from matching lines, which is what I presume your intent was.
The assumption is that `"${key}string"` matches at most *once* per line.

The small caveat is that you now may have to escape regular-expression metacharacters such as `.` in the value of `${key}` and also the literal part (`"string"`) to make it work as a regular expression.

With the same assumption and caveat, you can try this POSIX-compliant `awk` solution:

```
key="some"
value=$(awk -F "${key}string" 'NF >= 2 { print $2 }')
```

That said, if there could be *multiple* matches, and you needed the strings *between* the matches on each line, it is possible to adapt this solution.